# different login pages on sites on sensenet

Tags: sensenet

I create more than one site on sensenet and I want to specify an login page for each site.
On site properties I can define the login page but that is not working... (I think). Every time I access without the login made I receive the follow message:

> 404 error The requested resource could not be found Please make sure
>   that the url is spelled correctly.
>
> To go to the main page, click here

It shouldn't go to my login page defined on site settings?

[image: login page on site settings]

[image: "page not found" without login]

What am I not picking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add at least one site URL to your new site, and also check if "Everyone" has "open" and "run application" permission on the new login page.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a question of permissions.